# Esprima error 404 Not Found in npm install

Tags: reactjs, npm, esprima

I'm trying to install all dependencies in my react project, but when I run npm install I'm getting some errors related to esprima:

```
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://codeload.github.com/ariya/esprima/legacy.tar.gz/master
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404  'esprima@https://github.com/ariya/esprima/tarball/master' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Did anyone experience this error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue after downgrade my npm version from 7.14.0 to v6.14.13. It may not be the best solution, but it was the only way I could get rid of this problem.